# Swift Build no such command

Tags: openstack-swift

python-swiftclient 3.0.0
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I type in swift build and it returns the list of swift commands and says at the end no such command.  Could not find anyone describing this specific command line response.

Comment: Try to install `swift` with `sudo apt-get install python-swiftclient python3-swiftclient`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use either `python-swiftclient` either your PATH is wrong.
If `swift --version` returns:

```
python-swiftclient 3.0.0
```

Then you aren't currently calling swift build system. Check this link and update your swift release [here](https://swift.org/getting-started/).
Else check that you call the right `swift` executable by doing:

```
which swift
```

The output is the executable you are actually calling.

Answer (score 0):

Environmental variable failure
just
source ~/.bashrc

Comment: It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the entire swift environment is needed, so visit the [swift download page](https://www.swift.org/download/), and choose your system (mine is ubuntu 18.04):

```
$ wget https://download.swift.org/swift-5.5.2-release/ubuntu1804/swift-5.5.2-RELEASE/swift-5.5.2-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz
$ tar -xf swift-5.5.2-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz
$ PATH=~/swift-5.5.2-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04/usr/bin:$PATH
```

This solution worked perfect for me.